# How to get phonon4qt5 to work with QT5?

Tags: c++, qt5, phonon

I'm trying to get phonon4qt5 to work with QT5 but I'm getting:

> WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
>   WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect  Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName ) to  Phonon::AudioOutput ( no objectName ).

I've installed all the phonon related packages with apt.
I've added phonon4qt5 to my QT += in the .pro and LIBS += -L/home/fred/phonon-4.8.3/build5/phonon -lphonon4qt5 (tried several paths I found on my system)
And I've included these in my header:

```
#include <phonon4qt5/phonon/AudioDataOutput>
#include <phonon4qt5/phonon/AudioOutput>
#include <phonon4qt5/phonon/MediaObject>
#include <phonon4qt5/phonon/SeekSlider>
#include <phonon4qt5/phonon/VolumeSlider>
#include <phonon4qt5/phonon/AudioOutput>
```

Can someone point me to the correct direction?

(please don't suggest to use QMultimedia, since that's what I'm trying to get away from since there is no way to get the intensity of the sound output being played (in order to build a VU Meter..))

On the .cpp side I'm just doing:

```
   Phonon::MediaObject *music =
       Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::MusicCategory,
                            Phonon::MediaSource("/home/fred/cpp/config/rol1.ogg"));
   music->play();
```

Thank you for all your time and attention :-)

Best regards.

Fred.

Comment: with the phonon4qt5 version 4.8.3, apt-package installation seemed improper myself as well. However, validating this on the "synaptic" and fixing the missing libraries, as shown on the error panel fixed. My case it cribbed for the "libphononexperimental". For your case, it seems to be not have properly installed the phonon-backend-null. also, you can refer to the "apt-get install" suggestions about required/missing packages. See, if that helps.